# python to change all filenames based on list

Tags: python, dictionary, rename

I have a folder which has a list of files.
I have two dictionaries which has original filenames and new filenames.

```
FldName = r'C:\Users\Shei\Documents\Test'
oldFname = {'mangoes.txt', 'apple.txt', 'banana.txt'}
NewFname = {'random.txt', 'example1.txt', 'something.txt'}
```

I understand I can use the following to rename a single file

```
import os  
os.rename('Apple.txt','example1.txt')
```

but I am not sure, how do I bulk rename files based on list in the dictionary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: ```{mangoes.txt, apple.txt, banana.txt}``` is a set. And the elements should be in quotes

Comment: And the order is not preserved if you use `set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to zip the lists together

```
import os

FldName = r'C:\Users\Shei\Documents\Test'
oldFname = ['mangoes.txt', 'apple.txt', 'banana.txt']
NewFname = ['random.txt', 'example1.txt', 'something.txt']

for i, j in zip(oldFname,NewFname):
    os.rename(os.path.join(FldName,i),os.path.join(FldName,j))
```

Answer (score 0):

`set`s are unordered, try making them lists:

```
FldName = r'C:\Users\Shei\Documents\Test'
oldFname = ['mangoes.txt', 'apple.txt', 'banana.txt']
NewFname = ['random.txt', 'example1.txt', 'something.txt']
for x, y in zip(oldFname, NewFname):
    os.rename(os.path.join(FldName, x), os.path.join(FldName, y))
```